# New Microsoft Word office add-in not showing add-in button in the Ribbon

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm working on this [Official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visual-studio) from Microsoft where steps 1 and 2 of `Try it Out` section talks about showing an `add-in button` showing in the Ribbon. But when I run the app it shows the task pane on the right of main page but it does not show the add-in button in the Ribbon. I even tried `Insert-->My Add-ins-->MyAddInName` on the Main ribbon but still no luck. Following is the screenshot after I ran the app. You can click on the following picture to get a better view:

**UPDATE**: I'm using latest version of `Office 2016 Professional Plus` and latest build/Update of `VS2017 Community edition`.

[image]

Comment: What is your version and build of Office?

Comment: @RickKirkham I've added an UPDATE section to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-in Commands are not supported in Office 2016 Professional Plus, except in Outlook. For more information about where add-in commands are supported, see [Add-in Commands Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets).

Comment: But the tutorial says on top: `Applies to: Word 2016, Word for iPad, Word for Mac`

Comment: It applies to Office 365 Word. It applies to Word 2016 Professional Plus only in the sense that the add-in automatically opens and the buttons on the task pane work. This how add-ins are designed to behave when they are installed on a version of Office that does not support add-in commands. I will clarify the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you Rick. Your clarification on the tutorial will help other users/viewers of the tutorial, as well.